# Max recursion depth_Octave

Tags: recursion, vector, octave

A 'Max recursion depth reached' error is coming from this trivial code:

```
function [ y ] = A( X )
    y = 0;
    if(length(X) >=1)
        for j=1:length(X)
            y = y + A(j);
        endfor
    endif
end
```

Size of A is unknown. X is a vector.
Calculating sum of numbers.

Different unit tests are used to test this function. Am I missing something?

Comment: you can change the maximum recursion depth with `max_recursion_depth()` but when you face this error, chances are you have a bug on your code.

Comment: This is my only code.
What is the bug ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are recursively calling A with j=1, and the function does not meet the end condition (which is length(X) >= 1), as the length is never changed.

If you need to use recursion for this problem, you will need to remove the element from X before repeating the recursion call.

**Update**

Based on the documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Recursion.html) and [here](http://sunsite.univie.ac.at/textbooks/octave/octave_9.html), it appears that the following needs to be done for recursion (sorry, but I don't have octave where I am sitting atm so may be incorrect, please advise if so):

```
function [ y ] = A( X )
    y = 0;
    if(length(X) >=1)
        y = X(end);
        X(end) = [];
        y = y + A(X);
    endif
end
```

Comment: For j=1:length(X)

This statement means that j will increase by 1 in every loop till it reaches length(X). So the value of A(j) should change every loop right ?

(I used length(X)>=1 for iff the vector has non-zero length i.e it contains some numbers.

Comment: No Loop ? You forgot the loop i guess

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was a question about recursion.  It appears that you are creating recursion by using y = y + A(j), as A is it's own function name.  So while you are indeed looping, the system continually creates new calls to A, which causes the function to call itself infinitely (perhaps what I said is a little confusing).  If this is unwanted behavior, then perhaps you should use the loop and 'y = y + x(j)' instead.

Comment: I figured it out. I just used the sum function in Octave to sum the  numbers of the vector. 
Moreover, in my code, i was return variable and the sum variable i.e. y are same. So infinite recursion.

Comment: Glad it has worked out for you.  I would have considered a more stock-standard approach but was more concerned that you wanted to learn the recursion process instead.  Hopefully it's all downhill from here!

Answer (score 0):

Your original function is correct. (The edited version (with the loop) doesn't work at all.) The line X(end)=[]; makes X shorter by one for each call ensuring that the recursion terminates.

```
function [ y ] = A( X )
    y = 0;
    if(length(X) >=1)
        y = X(end);
        X(end) = [];
        y = y + A(X);
    endif
end
```

The problem is that Octave provides a very limited recursion depth (default max_recursion_depth() == 256). So, with the default set, A(1:400) generates the error message you observed.  One can increase it slightly, e.g. max_recursion_depth(512) allows A(1:400) to work (as expected) but A(1:500) causes Octave 4.2.1 to crash (at least on my machine), but this seems to be a bug in Octave and not a misunderstanding of the language.